# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-entities

I am getting Specified cast is not valid error in this method

```
public Dictionary<byte, string> getTeamList(int id1, Dictionary<byte, int> myList)
{    
    Dictionary<byte, string> result = new Dictionary<byte, string>();
    var query= _dataContext.usp_getItem();
    foreach(var item in query)
    {
        if (myList.ContainsKey(item.ID)
        {
            int count= _dataContext.usp_getCountPerID(id1, item.ID).FirstOrDefault().Count;
            if (myList[item.ID] > count)
            {
                result.Add(item.ID, item.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(item.ID, item.Name);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting the InvalidCastException error at this line:

```
int count = _dataContext.usp_getCountPerID(item.ID).FirstOrDefault().Count;
```

The type of Count is int. It works when I comment out this line of code.

**UPDATE**

usp_getCountPerID looks like this:

```
@ID1 INT,
@ID2 TINYINT
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Count  //I'm changing this name so it's actually not "Count"
FROM   Table
WHERE  ID1 = @ID1
       AND ID2 = @ID2
```

Comment: What does `usp_getCountPerID` return?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - it returns ISinglResult which contains an int value

Comment: If `ISingleResult` doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, then calling `FirstOrDefault` on it doesn't make sense.

Comment: if you change this to be `var count= _dataContext.usp_getCountPerID(item.TeamID).FirstOrDefault().Count;` do you still get the error..? what is the value of count before the if statement

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I tried but still got the same error.. I had initialized count to 0 first and didn't work either :-(

Comment: could you then explain what `usp_getCountPerID` or what it returns or what the method looks like this would help

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I edited my question to add how usp_getCountPerID looks like. I was omitting one of parameters make my question simpler, but I added that as well. It should return a table containing just one value which should be an int..

Comment: have you run that query separately in SQL ..? if so how many rows does it return..? my concerns are about the foreach statement if you return only one value then you do not need a FirstOrDefault you just need to return the Count from the _dataContext.usp_getCountPerID() method call

Comment: @DJKRAZE - the query works fine in SQL and it returns just one row and one column. The foreach statement is for another query result from [usp_getItem], which returns ISingleResult containing ID in byte and Name in string, and it contains multiple rows.

Comment: now that you have explained your issue a bit more clearer I would take a look at @sa_ddam213 suggestion

Comment: What is the type of `Count` finally?

Comment: @abatishchev - type of Count is int32

Comment: `Int32` but not `Nullable<Int32>`? Weird.

Comment: Is it possible that the first iteration returns `Int32` and the second iteration returns `Nullable<Int32>` in the foreach loop? The first iteration works and that's when I can check the type of `Count`, but the second iteration stops at the line of foreach, so I can't see the type of `Count` in the second iteration. Could it be the issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best solution but I changed my stored procedure to get count to this:

```
@SessionID INT
SELECT ID, COUNT(Member) AS Count
FROM   Table
WHERE  SessionID = @SessionID 
GROUP BY ID
```

which returns a table containing ID and the total count of Members for each ID

So, instead of getting values for the count per ID inside the foreach loop, I retrieve the list of ID and Count before entering the foreach loop and this works..

I still don't understand why I was getting the casting error, so I would mark it as answer if someone could explain what I was missing.

Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your returning the count from the database you may have to cast as `int`

perhaps

```
int count = (int)_dataContext.usp_getCountPerID(item.ID).FirstOrDefault().Count;
```

or

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(_dataContext.usp_getCountPerID(item.ID).FirstOrDefault().Count);
```

if that fails also you could check the `type` of object `Count` is which may help in finding out whats going on.

```
var count = _dataContext.usp_getCountPerID(item.ID).FirstOrDefault().Count;
Type t = count.GetType();
```

Or perhaps the Database is returning `null` so try

```
int? count = (int?)_dataContext.usp_getCountPerID(item.ID).FirstOrDefault().Count;
```

Comment: Updated answer with stuff that may help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Both didn't work so I checked the type of object. The type of count is int32 on the first iteration of foreach loop, but then I get the InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code error on the second iteration and stops. I check if myList contains the ID, and it skips if myList doesn't contain the ID...

Comment: hmmm, any chance the DB is returning `null` you mat want to try `int?`